# Detect which type of d3 scale I am working with

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm writing some charting components using D3. Some of these components are deliberately generic, so they can be re-used in various scenarios.

In one function, I receive a scale object as an argument. I want to take slightly different actions depending on whether this is a linear scale, a time scale, or an ordinal scale.

However I cannot easily see how to detect which type of scale I've got.

- `instanceof` does not work - these objects aren't create with `new` and don't have a prototype set. They are Function objects with additional attributes added to them.
- `typeof` returns 'object' in all cases (naturally)
- at least in the case of ordinal scales, there are some additional attributes that I can use for detection, so I can use:

  ```
  if (scale.rangeBound) {
      // do something specific to ordinal scales
  }
  ```

  but that does not seem to be the case for different types of quantative scales, which seem to have identical sets of attributes.
- I can add some attribute to each scale I create indicating it's type, but I would prefer not to as it reduces the generality of the functions I am creating (they would require scales passed to them which had these attributes added). Also I would risk clashing with some attribute added by a future version of D3.

In fact this question could be extended to many of the objects within D3. Is there any way to tell them apart?

Comment: In general, you're not meant to do this. Could you elaborate a bit on why you need to distinguish between the different types?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I want to apply different nice() counts to linear scales compared to time scales within a particular type of chart. Why do you say I'm not meant to do that?

Comment: The way the D3 scales are set up you can't easily distinguish between the different types -- you're not meant to be able to do that. Could you derive the type of scale from the data rather the object?

Answer (score 4):

You could insulate yourself against code changes by coding your check against the behaviour of the scales, than it's internals

```
function checkType(scale) {
    var s = scale.copy();
    if (s.domain([1, 2]).range([1, 2])(1.5) === 1)
        return "ordinal";
    else if (s.domain([1, 2]).range([1, 2]).invert(1.5) === 1.5)
        return "linear";
    else if (s.domain([1, 2]).range([1, 2]).invert(1.5) instanceof Date)
        return "time";
    else
        return "not supported";
}
```

Note, that this would still trip up for other / custom scales that have the same behaviour.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/enon2rjs/

Comment: Interesting idea, although I don't like the overhead involved in copying the scale and calling up various methods just to judge it's type. It feels like there should be an easier way.

Comment: You could store the domain and range, do the operation directly on the scale argument and then restore the domain and scale before you return. I just used scale because it seemed clearer to show what was happening.

Answer (score 2):

I played around a little, and found something that might be useful. I'm not sure how reliable this is, but comparing the string version of a method that all three scales share seems to give the desired result.

The statement

```
console.log(""+ordinal.domain);
```

Prints some representation of the function ordinal.domain (which, at least for me, is the source code). This should be the same for any two instances of ordinal.domain. It seems to work, but it does feel like there should be a better way.

```
var ordinal = d3.scale.ordinal();
var ordinal2 = d3.scale.ordinal();
var time = d3.time.scale();
var range = d3.scale.linear();


ordinal.domain([1,2]);
ordinal.range([2,3])

console.log(""+ordinal.domain == ""+ordinal2.domain); //true
console.log(""+time.domain == ""+ordinal.domain); //false
console.log(""+range.domain == ""+time.domain); //false
```

Comment: This is a really good idea - you might want to make it more generic by doing something like String(ordinal2.copy) == String(d3.scale.ordinal().copy) i.e. use a more generic method (copy) and use a new (or closured) instance for the comparison.

Comment: Like you say, it feels like there should be a better way. For one thing the standard does not guarantee that the string representation of the function will be the source code, or even be unique. Still, so far seems the best solution. BTW, can use toString rather than concatenating with an empty string.